# Arduino 9 Axes Motion Shield

Tags: arduino, imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

Can I use this arduino shield as IMU in my mobile robot ?
Arduino 9 Axes Motion Shield: http://www.arduino.org/learning/reference/9-Axes-Motion

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236570/arduino-9-axes-motion-shield/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would say it should work as long as you can make all of the parts work together. Here is a driver for the BNO055: https://github.com/mdrwiega/bosch_imu_driver ....and you could use some of that with some of this: http://www.hessmer.org/blog/2010/11/21/sending-data-from-arduino-to-ros/

or for a much easier method, use this: https://github.com/RTIMULib/RTIMULib-Arduino and probably communicate with rosserial- http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial and here is something to help you install it if you are running kinetic -http://answers.ros.org/question/236351/rosserial-on-ros-kinetic/

good luck

---

Originally posted by [matrhint](https://answers.ros.org/users/27390/matrhint/) with karma: 52 on 2016-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0